# Use Form Field Data in Link?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to revamp something the kind folks her helped me develop several months ago. 
I'm just trying to make a simple download dropdown menu. That is, the user selects an item to download from a single dropdown and then clicks a download button to download it. I'm trying to use the "value" associated to the "option" but it's not quite working.

My script:

```
jQuery("form.template").on('blur', ':input', function(){
    var diecut = jQuery(".diecut").text()
    var linkText = "http://www.theuglybug.com/templates/" + diecut;
    jQuery("#showmehref").text(linkText);
    jQuery("#mylink").attr('href', linkText);
});
```

My form:

```
<form class="template" name="template" id="template">
<select name="diecut" id="diecut" class="diecut">
  <option value="TT602_21781_2up.pdf">TT602_21781_2up</option>
  <option value="TT801_17237.pdf">TT801_17237</option>
  <option value="TT1067_CD_Holder.pdf">TT1067_CD_Holder</option>
  <option value="TT1163_28543_2up.pdf">TT1163_28543_2up</option>
  <option value="TT1163_28543_DIE.pdf">TT1163_28543_DIE</option>
  <option value="TT1237_32028.pdf">TT1237_32028</option>
  <option value="TT10804_18990_2up.pdf">TT10804_18990_2up</option>
</select> 
<a id="mylink" class="blueButton" href="#">Download</a>
</form>
```

My rough development site:

http://theuglybug.com/timbertech/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do it's to get the value and not the text of the dropdown menu option.

```
var diecut = jQuery(".diecut").val();
```

Comment: Bingo bango bongo! You are an officer and a gentlemen. That was it. I should have realized that was the difference between my earlier script and this one. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Didn't know about that limitation, I only knew about the 15 minutes one. How you selected the other questions you asked?